# Is there a way to set default enduro.js culture?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, handlebars.js, enduro.js

Working on a enduro.js website project, I am wondering if there is a way to set the default culture ?

For the moment, it defaults to EN, even when adding DE ES & FR for instance... I'd like te get FR (or what ever other culture) as default culture, but i don't know if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it's not too late.

Yes, you can and it's pretty easy.

Within your project, there is a file named enduro.json, there you can find all the cultures you have added so far. the first item is always the default one.

So, if you want French, for instance, as the default culture, you just put it as the first item inside the cultures array. Don't forget to restart the server to note the changes.

```
"cultures": [
  "fr", // default culture
  "en"
]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Alex I have another question on Enduro.js, if you could help it would be great :) (see the enduro.js tag or via my account).